# PHP - pcntl_fork() not running child process

Tags: php, pcntl

I am running following code. It's only running parent process.

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();

if($pid) {
  // parent process runs what is here
  echo $pid;
  echo "parent\n";
}
else {
  // child process runs what is here
  echo "child\n";
}
```

Output: 1553172parent

I am unable to understand, Why is not running child process.

Comment: What is the exact value of `$pid`? According to docs: _On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent's thread of execution,_ so is that not the child's PID you are printing out? http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Comment: What platform are you on? The value `1553172` is unusually large for a linux system, where `$pid<32768` should be.

Comment: Architecture: x86_64
Operating System: linux

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski : My code is never printing "Child"